# Updating a row and keeping original data

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to update a column in the database. The clients want to add XR+ original information in the row. so an example would be

```
Sumary Doctype
Med    10
```

they want everything with a doctype of 10 to have the summary + XR in the from of it.

so they want

```
Sumary    Doctype
XR Med    10
```

This is for oracle 11g. I see this as an update but is there a simple way of doing it all at wants instead of

```
update document 
set summary = XR med
where summary in ( list all instances) and doctype = 10?
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
update document 
set summary = 'XR ' || summary 
where doctype = 10
```

Comment: Thanks allot i knew it was an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your case

`update document 
set summary = 'XR ' + summary
where summary in ( list all instances) and doctype = 10`